# Where am I? - A location riddle

Tags: riddle

> If I look up, I see nothing.
>
> If I look right, I see no one.
>
> If I look down, I see a lock that is a key.
>
> And if I look left, I see back.
>
> Where am I?

*-*
*Explain every line of the riddle in your answer*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you somewhere around

> here?
>  [image]
>  <sub><sup>(Image is from https://www.bbc.com/news/business-47460499)</sup></sub>

If I look up, I see nothing.

> No keys above the numbers row, as typewriters don't have function keys

If I look right, I see no one.

> Old typewriters usually only had keys for the numbers 2 to 9 (this particular model has a zero too), you were supposed to substitute the similar looking letters for 1 and 0 instead. (I seem to recall the capital I being the usual replacement for 1, even though a lowercase ell would look a lot more like a modern day "1".)

If I look down, I see a lock that is a key.

> The caps lock (or here, "shift lock") key

And if I look left, I see back.

> On some typewriters, like the one in the picture, the back space key is to the left of the numbers row.

Where am I?

> You are in **SPACE**!

as in

> maybe your typewriter has the words on the "back space" key written on a single line, in which case it would make extra sense that to your left you can see only "back", not the entire "back space" key.

Well, at least that seemed like a fun idea at the time :-)

Comment: Eh, close enough. I'll count it.